# Agents playing against each other (Reinforcement Learning)

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

To train my reinforcement model to play a two player game I could either play by myself or let it play against a second instance of itself. Are there any drawbacks which I have to take care of? Some sort of local minima which they might fall into when playing the same moves over and over again?
My idea is that a minimum exploration rate will keep them learning and exploring.

By the way, whats the name of this learning method? Back then I thought it's multi-agent learning. Now I see that this topic is about splitting tasks and cooperating agents. I have been looking for papers about this, but it looks like this is just the usual way to learn multiplayer games.

Are there other ways of training I might miss, despite learning by observing games which have been recorded?

Comment: It's often called self-play reinforcement learning.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thank you very much! That gives me some papers to study